# Curl stop browser sending Get Requests

Tags: php, http, curl, get

I wrote this script

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $address);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookieFileLocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookieFileLocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 25); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);


$response = curl_exec($ch);  

echo ($response);

curl_close($ch);
```

When I execute the script the site will be loaded but also some other get requests are sent by the browser. How can I stop the browser sending more get requests?
I want to follow the requests I write so I can see which request loads which part of the site. First I just want to see what gets loaded when I send the request I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do some sort of proxy, using curl to fetch some other html page, and then forward it onto the browser? You will have to rewrite the HTML and CSS and JS in that page so that all requests for other resources (images, fonts, flash, etc...) point back at your server and your proxy script. Otherwise, if the HTML you're forwarding contains any absolute (and/or `<base>`'d) addresses, you will not be able to prevent the browser from reaching out and fetching those resources directly.

Comment: No I just want to understand how curl works. For example I load a site. There are 10 http get requests until the site is fully loaded. Now I want to see what gets loaded with which request.

Comment: Curl fetches only what you tell it to. If the retrieved html contains images/javascript/flash/java/etc.... curl will NOT fetch those, as a regular browser would.

Comment: When I use the code I've posted above, the whole page gets loaded.

Comment: Yes, because you're fetching the page's html and sending it to the browser. The browser automatically fetches all referenced resources in a page. If you don't want the browser to do this, then force it to NOT treat the page as html via either `echo html_entities($response)` or `header('Content-type: text/plain'); echo $response` ... or both.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve but the best bet would be to monitor when you get a request back from cURL and once these are retrieved successfully then you would then process them.

This cURL request would only be sent ONCE during the script loading as to send this multiple times you would need to use a loop such as a while or foreach to achieve this. No other GET requests would be sent from loading the PHP script provided.

Comment: But then I cannot see what is already loaded because the php script would refresh everytime. For example: I send a get request to a page where a picture is. The second get request would be to get the image. I just want to get the site without the picture so I have to send just one request and "cancel" the request for the picture.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Well the way I would approach this would be too download the page once and then remove the image from the received html code. You could do this by using PHP's DOMDocument object to remove the img tag from the page. This may be useful :) http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php

Comment: I think this is what you want to do. There is no need to download the page multiple times to achieve this...

Comment: Yes but what if there are pictures, videos and stylesheets? Would be easier to tell the browser to stop loading the page after the first request.